# C++ where these objects are stored heap or stack?

Tags: c++, stack, heap-memory

I wrote this code and could someone explain how many objects are created in heap and stack? Is myStudent object in heap or stack?
Second question, is main method itself and the things inside of main method stored in stack?

```
class Student
{
public:
    Student()
    {
        id = 0;
    }
private:
    int id;
};
Student studentCreator()
{
    Student* s = new Student();
    return *s;
}
int main()
{
    Student myStudent = studentCreator();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where do you think they are stored? and why would you write code like this? don't use `new` and raw owning pointers

Comment: There is nothing in C++ related to heap and stack memory.  C++ uses automatic storage duration and dynamic storage duration.  Where those are actually stored, C++ doesn't care.

Comment: `s` on the stack and `*s` is on the heap (which is leaked since it is never deallocated). `studentCreator()` return a copy of `*s` which is assigned to `myStudent` which is on the stack frame for `main`.

Comment: @NathanOliver "heap" is the usual name of the memory area used for dynamic data, "stack" is the name of the memory area used for automatic data. Any relationship with the OS segments with the same names is purely coincidental.

Comment: @NathanOliver C++ indeed uses stack and/or registers for automatic variables, will almost always use the heap for explicit allocated memory (unless a special allocator is used), and will use static data/bss memory for the rest.

Comment: P.s. `Student() : id(0) {}`, or even just declare `int id=0;` and remove the constructor.

Comment: Also noteworthy that this code leaks memory. The necessary `delete` can't be done, since the address of the allocated object is lost.

Comment: @Barmar What would you call the memory area, which is the backup of a placement new then? It's used for _dynamic data_ as well, no?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Placement new doesn't allocate any memory at all, it uses whatever memory area the address points to.

Comment: @Barmar Sure, I well know that. Though, if I am right in my interpretation of the standard terminology, it's still a _dynamic allocation_, no matter if the memory backing was allocated at the _"stack"_, no?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I simply find these pedantic complaints about common terminology pointless and more likely to confuse people than help.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ placement new is not considered to perform any allocation. The resulting object's storage duration is unclear. I'm not sure you can accurately assign storage duration to a placement new'ed object.

Comment: @Barmar I can agree with that. But there must be a reasoning why it isn't mentioned in the c++ standard. I suspect it's because it's an OS thing, rather than a definition essential for the language.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Standard go out of their way to describe things in an abstract way, to avoid the appearance of specifying implementation details.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That's exactly my point. You cannot, while for _automatic storage_ you can tell.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean that placement new over storage that has automatic storage results in an object with automatic storage, that is not accurate. The new'ed object will not be destroyed (though its storage will). Edit : New expression specifies that it always results in an object with dynamic storage duration, even placement new.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux No, you misunderstood. I meant that placement new still is dynamic allocaiton, no matter where the backing memory comes from. But well, as _@barmar_ mentioned it's a bit of useless quibbling if it comes to practical implementations of the c++ language. _"New expression specifies that it always results in an object with dynamic storage duration, even placement new."_ that's all I wanted to tell.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ah yes, _allocation_ and _duration_ make a difference.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I removed my last comment because it is a matter of interpretation. Placement new *does* call an allocation function but the placement allocation functions that can called do not allocate.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Which makes me wonder now: Does a constuctor function _allocate_ the class members (in terms of correct memory layout)?

Comment: No matter whatever. This question is the umpteenth gazillionth dupe of already asked and answered questions here (and most of them were asked in better ways).

Answer (score 2):

myStudent is on the stack. During the function call you are creating something in the heap and losing its reference.

Comment: will edit that. ;)

Comment: Believe it or not, the compiler can store `myStudent` in a register since it only has a single integer field.  With most processors, registers are not in heap nor stack.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have `myStudent` on the stack because that function creates a student on the heap but return it dereferencing it, then you have a memory leak. The main function is stored on the stack by the operating system.

Comment: "The main function is stored on the stack" -- It is unclear what you mean with these words. Do you mean the actual code for the function `main` is stored on the stack (which would be wrong)?